# Issue with parsing JSON with AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, json, post, afnetworking

Using AFNetworking unable to get the data from server.

here is my some of code,

```
NSString *serviceUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL,serviceName];
NSString *paramString = [NSString stringWithFormat:SERVICE_PARAMS, parametersString, DB_NAME];
NSData* data = [paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *parametersDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [data length]];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:SERVICE_TIMEOUT];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
manager POST:serviceUrl parameters:parametersDictionary progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate onServiceSuccess:(NSDictionary *)responseObject];
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate onServiceFailed];
    }
}];
```

i am getting response like this, <5b5b7b22 636f756e 74223a22 30227d5d 5d>
but my actual response working fine in Postman.
here is the postman Screen[image]

Comment: You used `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`, so response object is of class `NSData`. You could use yourself `NSArray *myJSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];`, or change the `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`  and use the `AFJSONResponseSerializer` (or something like that, not sure about the real name), which will do the deserialization for you.

Comment: Also, note that even serialized, your JSON answer is an NSArray, not a NSDictionary (as you seem to have casted it). You may be want to do `[self.delegate onServiceSuccess:myJSONObjectResponseArray[0][0]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` (default response serializer), so `responseObject` is a `NSData` object (`<5b5b7b22 636f756e 74223a22 30227d5d 5d>` is the basic `description` of a `NSData` object).

You can replace `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` with the JSON correspondant one: `AFJSONResponseSerializer`, or do the serialization yourself:

```
NSArray *myJSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
```

Note that your JSON is an Array of Arrays of Dictionaries. So doing this: `[self.delegate onServiceSuccess:(NSDictionary *)responseObject];` is just a cast, and a bad one.
If you really want just `{"count":"96"}`, do `[self.delegate onServiceSuccess:myJSONObjectResponseArray[0][0]];` instead.

Comment: working fine. i am changing the dictionary to array.